# Trash before string

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

I use Tasm. Trash appear before first string but not second. I set dollar($) to the end of string

```js
.model tiny

CSEG segment
assume cs:CSEG, ds:CSEG, es:CSEG, ss:CSEG 
org 100h

Begin:
    push offset msgOrig1
    push offset msgOrig2

    call ProcParams

    ret

    ProcParams proc near 
        push bp
        mov bp, sp
        add bp, 2

        mov ah,09h    
        mov dx, [bp]
        int 21h
        mov dx, [bp+2]
        int 21h

        pop bp

        ret 4
    ProcParams endp

    msgOrig1 db 'Hello$'
    msgOrig2 db 'world$'
CSEG ends
end Begin
```

Any suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the offsets wrong, you forgot to compensate for either the return address or the `push bp`. That's 4 bytes in total, not 2. Also you are printing the strings reversed, and you don't really need to add to `bp` either. A possible fix:

```
ProcParams proc near 
    push bp
    mov bp, sp

    mov ah,09h    
    mov dx, [bp+6]
    int 21h
    mov dx, [bp+4]
    int 21h

    pop bp

    ret 4
ProcParams endp
```

Learn to use a debugger.